# raise... from: use pdb to move into the stack of the wrapped exception

Tags: python, python-3.x

Python 3 features the raises... from construct:

```
def f():
    assert False

def g():
    try:
        f()
    except Exception as e:
        raise Exception('this is a wrapper') from e

g()
```

The above prints out:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "raise_from.py", line 6, in g
    f()
  File "raise_from.py", line 2, in f
    assert False
AssertionError

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "raise_from.py", line 10, in <module>
    g()
  File "raise_from.py", line 8, in g
    raise Exception('this is a wrapper') from e
Exception: this is a wrapper
```

Which is very nice and neat.
However, when I try debugging the program, either with command-line pdb or PyCharm, I cannot find any way to jump onto the stack of the wrapped exception. How do I retrieve the local variables of f() at the moment it raised the original AssertionError?